# Delphi ADO + MySQL + Developer Express Grid

Tags: mysql, delphi, devexpress, ado

I have problems using Mysql with MySQL Connector, I can successfully connect to a database on the net via ODBC, and in my grid I can display many records, however in the grid (Developper express) I seem to be unable to scroll. i think it is related to cursor locations etc etc, but I am not sure.

also recordcount and recno seems also not functioning, altho I can scroll back and forth

what will be the correct ADOConnection and ADOQuery properties to successfully use mysql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems better to use data acess components that are specialized for MySQL.
MyDAC from DevART shoud be good enough. I do not use their MyDAC, but their SDAC (MS SQL access) successfully work in most of my projects.
Or there should be other third-party components, may be free also.

Comment: what if customers just want to use excel, or some other unknown db that might use ADO, would this still work?

Comment: Nope, DEVART components are dedicated for DB servers (list of supported servers are here: http://www.devart.com/ru/dac.html . If you need a fully-functional solution for ADO this should be inspected: I do not like ADO and its Delphi implementation and prefer to avoid it as often as it possible :)

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest to use 3d party components, like [Anydac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/). They will work with MySQL right out of the box.

Comment: will this work with any database engine ?, how will it cope with example MS Access or MS Excel?  some excel files uses formulas which causes alot of trouble

Comment: Anydac, afaik, has native connectivity for Access and through their ODBC link will work with Excel. Regarding formulas - check your self of with their technical support. You will like it ! :)

Answer (score 1):

With the DevExpress grid check out the [GridMode](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UMXw4M3NlYXJjaHRleHQ9Z3JpZG1vZGU=) and associated properties - this may have an effect. The [DevExpress support knowledge base](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) has many examples and questions about this. Also with some dataset types it's necessary to do something like:

```
dataset.Open;
dataset.Last;
dataset.First;
//...do stuff
```

in order to get the recordcount correct.